# How to use tf.concat() function?

Tags: tensorflow

I found a bug in `tf.concat`. The problem is:

> 'Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types
>   [float32, ] that don't all match'.

I do not know how to correct it.

```
for idx in range(1, num_layer):
      layer = Dense(layers[idx], W_regularizer=l2(reg_layers[idx]),activation='relu', name="layer%d" % idx)
      mlp_vector = layer(mlp_vector)
predict_vector = tf.concat([mf_vector, mlp_vector],-1)
```

Comment: How `Dense` `layers` and `layer` are defined? Consider adding some context

Comment: hello,this is my mf-vector:

mf_user_latent = Flatten()(MF_Embedding_User(user_input))
mf_item_latent = Flatten()(MF_Embedding_Item(item_input))